# How to remove standard New Opportunity button shown on Opportunity related list from Account object

Tags: opportunity, button, button-overrides, standardlayout

I would like to replace the New Opportunity button with a custom button so I can copy information from the Account into the non-editable required opportunity fields.
I've tried reviewing search layouts, custom buttons for each object but can't seem to figure it out..
Has anyone been able to remove the standard button and replace with a custom one?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "non-editable required opportunity fields"?  Please post a screenshot showing those fields.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Open respective Account page layout

Step 2: Open Opportunity Related list properties

Step 3: Open Button section

Step 4: uncheck New checkbox

[image]

[image]